# ArgumentException not caught when using BitmapImage.BeginInit()

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage, bitmapsource, argumentexception

Why when an ArgumentException occurs because image.jpg has an invalid metadata header does the first example catch the exception, and the second example does not?

Example 1:

```
try
{
Uri myUri = new Uri("http://example.com/image.jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
JpegBitmapDecoder decoder2 = new JpegBitmapDecoder(myUri,
                             BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat,
                             BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bitmapSource2 = decoder2.Frames[0];
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Example 2:

```
try
{
BitmapImage src = new BitmapImage();
src.BeginInit();
src.UriSource = new Uri("http://example.com/image.jpg");
src.EndInit();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be waiting until the image is requested to load it up, such as being set as the source for an `Image` control.

Perhaps it would give you an exception if you added

```
src.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
```

to your declarations.

Comment: I was setting the BitmapImage as the Background property on a border, but that was the first thing I checked. Even when I don't set the image as a source for something the exception still occurs.

Comment: To be clear, are you saying that both examples threw an exception, but that the exception was not caught in Example 2?

Comment: Yes. Both threw an exception whenever there is a problem with the image being loaded, but the exception was not caught in example 2.

Comment: I am not aware of any exceptions other than OutOfMemoryException or ExecutionEngineException that can evade a general catch block like that. Are you sure it's being thrown from there? Maybe try putting a breakpoint in the catch block; maybe the message box isn't getting shown for some reason.